# How to execute a shell command under Linux unsing QProcess?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, xrandr

I am trying to read the screen resolution from within a Qt application, but without using the GUI module.

So I have tried using:

```
xrandr |grep \* |awk '{print $1}'
```

command through *QProcess*, but it shows a warning and does not give any output:

> `unknown escape sequence:'\\*'`

Rewriting it with `\\\*` does not help, as it leads to the following error:

> `/usr/bin/xrandr: unrecognized option '|grep'\nTry '/usr/bin/xrandr --help' for more information.\n`

How can I solve that?

Comment: @scopchanov Thanks for editing the question .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use bash and pass the argument in quotes:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess process;
    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&process](){
       qDebug()<<process.readAllStandardOutput();
    });
    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [&process](){
       qDebug()<<process.readAllStandardError();
    });
    process.start("/bin/bash -c \"xrandr |grep \\* |awk '{print $1}' \"");
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
"1366x768\n"
```

Or:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("/bin/bash", {"-c" , "xrandr |grep \\* |awk '{print $1}'"});
```

Or:

```
QProcess process;
QString command = R"(xrandr |grep \* |awk '{print $1}')";
process.start("/bin/sh", {"-c" , command});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use QProcess to execute piped system commands like that, it is designed to run a single program with arguments Try:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("bash -c xrandr |grep * |awk '{print $1}'");
```

OR

```
QProcess process;
QStringList args = QString("-c,xrandr,|,grep *,|,awk '{print $1}'").split(",");
process.start("bash", args);
```

Comment: thanks, while this one do get me a result , this is printing the entire command output without filtering the first one.

Comment: still same issues. while on command line xrandr gives 1366x768 output. It gives the entire value through QProcess, Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192\neDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm\n   1366x768      59.97*+\n   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  \n   1024x768      60.04    60.00  \n   960x720       60.00  \n   928x696       60.05  \n   896x672       60.01    ...

Comment: What is the actual string (format) that you are trying to filter out?

Comment: Sorry, resolution like format , like this 1366x768.

Comment: Yeah, I see now, it doesn't seem to be passing the output through grep.  You could just use the process to call xrandr, read the output and use a regular expression to pull out the info you want.