# QProcess does not properly trigger executable .sh

Tags: c++, c++11, julia, qt5, qprocess

**Probelm**: I have been trying to run an executable file using `QProcess` triggering the executable file using a `QPushButton` and showing the whole result of the output on `QTextEdit` but without success.

**The error*: I don't see the whole output despite, following the official documentation I used `this->executeJuliaCheck->readAllStandardOutput()`

I have an executable file called `check_julia.sh` which is located in `/home/esoMars/Alignsys/scripts/check_julia.sh` which is in the `qrc` folder of a standard `Qt5` project. The file is very simple and is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Checking"
cd /home/esoMars/julia-1.7.3/bin
julia
```

If I type on my home folder the command `(base) eso@eso-Oryx-Pro:~$ julia` the folloing output appears:

```
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.3 (2022-05-06)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia>
```

All this happens because I use the command line.

**Desired goal**: I would like NOT to use a command line, but rather I am trying to use a small graphical user interface where to show the output of the same command`(base) eso@eso-Oryx-Pro:~$ julia`

The way I am doing it is by using a `QPushButton` that check if `julia` is installed and show the output on a `QTextEdit`.

Below what I have done so far:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void check_julia_installation();

private slots:
    void on_juliaCheckBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QProcess *executeJuliaCheck;
    void executeJulia(QString command);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <QStringLiteral>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // Check Julia Installation
    check_julia_installation();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::check_julia_installation()
{
    // Execution of the QProcess
    this->executeJuliaCheck = new QProcess(this);
    this->executeJuliaCheck->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    QObject::connect(this->executeJuliaCheck, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
            [this](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
            qDebug() << "CODE " << exitCode << exitStatus;

                if(exitCode == 0)
                {
                    QString stdOutput = QString::fromUtf8(this->executeJuliaCheck->readAllStandardOutput());
                    qDebug() << stdOutput;
                    ui->textEdit->setText(stdOutput);
                    ui->outputLineEdit->setText("SUCCESS: JULIA IS PROPERLY INSTALLED");
                }
                else
                {
                    QString stdErr = QString::fromUtf8(this->executeJuliaCheck->readAllStandardError());
                    qDebug() << stdErr;
                    QString stdOutput = QString::fromUtf8(this->executeJuliaCheck->readAllStandardOutput());
                    qDebug() << stdOutput;
                    ui->textEdit->setText(stdErr + "\n" + stdOutput);
                    ui->outputLineEdit->setText("CONNECTION ERROR: JULIA NOT PRESENT");
                }
                ui->juliaCheckBtn->setEnabled(true);
    });
}


void MainWindow::on_juliaCheckBtn_clicked()
{
  this->executeJuliaCheck->start("sh",QStringList() << "-c" << "echo /home/esoMars/Alignsys/scripts/check_julia.sh");

  if(! this->executeJuliaCheck->waitForStarted()) //default wait time 30 sec
      qWarning() << " cannot start process ";

  int waitTime = 60000 ; //60 sec
  if (! this->executeJuliaCheck->waitForFinished(waitTime))
           qWarning() << "timeout .. ";
  this->executeJuliaCheck->waitForFinished();

ui->juliaCheckBtn->setEnabled(true);

}
```

**Updates**

A user suggested to reduce the clicked button to the following statement. I tried that but unfortunately the `QProcess` does not do anything:

```
void MainWindow::on_juliaCheckBtn_clicked()
{
    this->executeJuliaCheck->waitForStarted();
    this->executeJuliaCheck->start("sh",QStringList() << "-c" << "echo /home/esoMars/Alignsys/scripts/check_julia.sh");
    ui->juliaCheckBtn->setEnabled(true);
}
```

I looked up `QProcess` quite a while before writing and searched a lot. I found quite a few posts that I read and studied to understand the problem. [One post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086771/how-to-start-a-shell-script-with-qprocess) suggested to look at `setWorkingDirectory` which I did but that didn't help much.

[Another posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407394/qt-run-shell-commands-via-qprocess) suggested to use for `waitForFinished()` just in case other processes are running but it is not my case. Despite a clean exit I don't see the whole output.  However, for debugging reasons I put `this->executeJuliaCheck->start("sh",QStringList() << "-c" << "echo /home/esoMars/Alignsys/scripts/check_julia.sh");` so that I could confirm the executable file read. However, *I still can't see the whole output*

I looked also at [additional posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264843/how-to-execute-a-shell-command-under-linux-unsing-qprocess) such as this one but I still could not figure out how to show the whole output.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: You said several times "I don't see the whole output" What output do you see?

Comment: @drescherjm, I refer to the out put of `julia`, which means show the banner on the screen. I would like to do it through a `QPushbutton` that triggers the executable I mentioned above. Hope that clarifies more.

Comment: Your calls to waitForFinished() are probably part of the problem especially since the answer says julia will wait for input meaning the spawned process wont finish. Also in Qt the GUI will not update until your function exits (so it returns to the Qt message loop) so waitForFinished() is usually a not the best practice in a GUI application outside a destructor.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @drescherjm, I have read several posts but still I could not find a solution to the problem. Could you please post how the code should be modified? That would really help a lot. I have been struggling a bit in the past couple of days to understand `QProcess`

Comment: Try commenting out both calls for `waitForFinished()` that you have in `on_juliaCheckBtn_clicked()` you also need to add an additional connect to this signal: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput)

Comment: if I comment out both `waitForFinished()` in `on_juliaCheckBtn_clicked()` and only remain with one i does not start the process unfortunately and I don't understand why.

Comment: `this->executeJuliaCheck->waitForStarted()` should ensure the process is started if possible.

Comment: Here is an additional QProcess example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016900/how-to-read-when-qprocess-need-user-input-with-qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016900/how-to-read-when-qprocess-need-user-input-with-qt)

Comment: I updated the answer with your suggestions but the `QProcess` does not start. In the question I added *Updates*. What am I missing?

Comment: In any case, the executable does not seem to be triggered, and I don't know why...

Comment: `"sh"` you may need the full path to `sh`

Comment: `this->executeJuliaCheck->waitForStarted();` must be after `start()` not before.

Comment: Sorry it is not working. I keep trying and hopefully I will find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to see the Julia banner in order to show it to the user.
The problem is that once started, the Julia process is waiting for the input.

This can be simply circumvented as:

```
$ echo "exit()" | julia --banner=yes
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.8.0 (2022-08-17)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

$
```

The above command produces the banner (so you can collect it by reading the standard output of your process) and then immediately exits.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I would like to show the output. Can you also add in the answer how should the code be modified? Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: I understand you are running `check_julia.sh` - so this is the command you should execute (`echo "exit()" | julia --banner=yes`). You could also send the `"exit()"` via the standard input stream directly from the C code. You will get the output on standard output stream (the code is for an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344807/read-qprocess-output-to-string). You could redirect it to file instead and read the file eg. `echo "exit()" | julia --banner=yes > file.txt`

Comment: Thanks for he additional comment. Could you please update your answer adding what you suggested please?

Comment: In any case, the executable does not seem to be triggered, and I don't understand why.

Comment: shouldn't you execute that simply as `bash /home/esoMars/Alignsys/scripts/check_julia.sh`? rather than use `-c` parameter etc?

Comment: That is exactly what I thought. But the executable won't start. Yes I tried without `-c` too but that didn't anything. I don't understand what I am missing.